# Limits of sequences: proofs

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I just had 2 questions on limits. I can do limit proof questions when they are basic and stuff. But with harder examples I get a bit stuck.

Prove 
$$
A(n) \to \infty \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty \text{ for } A(n)=\frac{n+7}{2+\sin(n)}
$$

And how do you determine if something has a limit; for example if I had 
$$
A(n)=\frac{n+((-1)^n)\cdot n^{0.5}}{(n^2+1)^{0.5}}
$$
Thanks for the help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to use the formal definition or what are you allowed to use to determine these limits?

When you look at:
$$\frac{n+7}{2+\sin n}$$
then clearly the numerator gets arbitrary large, while the numerator is bounded as follows:
$$-1 \le \sin n \le 1 \implies 1 \le 2+\sin n \le 3$$
That means you have:
$$\color{blue}{\frac{n+7}{3} \le  \frac{n+7}{2+\sin n}} \le n+7$$
Does that help? Focus on the blue inequality.

---

For the second one, use LaTeX to typeset it properly to avoid confusion.

Do you mean the limit of the following expression?

$$\frac{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}$$

If so: dividing numerator and denominator by $n$ and simplifying a bit will help to understand what happens for $n$ sufficiently large:

$$\frac{\frac{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n}}{\frac{\sqrt{1+n^2}}{n}} = \frac{1+\color{red}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}}{\sqrt{\color{red}{\frac{1}{n^2}}+1}}$$
What happens to the two red fractions for $n$ arbitrarily large?

Comment: Yes that the expression I meant. I have to use the epsilon-characterisation of a limit to find the answer. I don't know how, for example, prove that the expression has a limit when n tends to infinity using the  epsilon-characterisationAn=sqrt(5)+2/(n^2+sqrt(3))

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, we'll use the squeeze theorem.

$$1 \leq 2 + \sin n \leq 3$$
$$1 \geq \frac{1}{2+\sin n} \geq \frac13$$
$$n+7 \geq \frac{n+7}{2+\sin n} \geq \frac{n+7}3$$

Now just take the limits of the bounds to $\infty$, which shows the thing being bounded approaches $\infty$.

I'm not sure about the second one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I am deciphering your notation correctly, the denominator has a range between 1 and 3 (since $\sin(n)$ has a range between -1 and 1). So as $n$ gets really large, the numerator gets large but the denominator does not. Does that help you see why the limit is infinity?

The second one is hard to decipher, but it looks like it may not be continuous. The $(-1)^n$ implies a function for integers. Maybe it oscillates. If you could plot it (like on Desmos), and it oscillates, then as $n$ gets really large, the difference between the numerator and denominator grows smaller and settles down to a finite value. Sorry, I can't help you find the specific value.